# form validation with preg_match in callback not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, codeigniter-3

I have questions about my codeigniter form validation. I try to validate the input form for name so it will generate error if user using symbol like `">?<*&%^$"`. Here is my code:

My rules:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'Name', 'trim|required|callback_name_check',
            array(

                'name_check' => '%s should not using symbols'
            )
    );
```

This is my callback function (I tried to modify this from the last example I saw, so I thought the problem was here)

```
public function password_check($str)
    {
       if (preg_match('#[<>?&%$#@]#', $str)) {
         return TRUE;
       }
       return FALSE;
    }
```

I have tried another example from another StackOverflow answer to use / as delimiter (like this --> `[/<>?&%$#@/]`), but still, doesn't work. I'll appreciate your help sensei :)

Answer (score 0):

**Validation should be**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'Name', 'trim|required|callback_name_check');
```

**Inside call back function**

```
public function name_check($str)
{
    if (preg_match('#[<>?&%$#@]#', $str)) {
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        #adding new validation error should be
        $this->form_validation->set_message('full_name', '%s should not using symbols'); # input field name should come to first
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

> **Note**: Didn't validate REGEX which you have posted